# Can I modify stdin descriptor for particular process?

Tags: linux, process, file-descriptor

Here is the scenario:

I opened 3 terminals: term1, term2, term3.
PID of term1 is 6549.

```
ps -fp 6549
```

gives:

```
bc        6549  3642  0 11:07 pts/8   00:00:00 bash
```

Now, on terminal 2 I typed

```
tail -f /proc/6549/fd/0
```

So far nothing happens, but ok, all in all nothing is being processed by process 6549.
Now on terminal3 I execute:

```
echo "any kind of text" | write $USER pts/8
```

which is just sending text. Output on terminal1 is ok, but nothing appears on tailed descriptor. Is it possible to see input of data passed to execute by process 6549? How does 6549 use files inside /proc/6549/fd directory ?

Edit:
Same about stdout: I cannot see any output of tail, output on terminal with above PID is ok.

Comment: XY problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Reading from a terminal reads input from the terminal's keyboard (real or virtual). Writing to a terminal writes output to the terminal's screen.

What you're doing is writing to the terminal's screen and expecting that output to loop back as keyboard input instead of being displayed:

[image: Illustration showing that data written to a terminal does not loop back as keyboard input]

The answer is no, you can not do that. If you want to run a program in a terminal session where multiple processes can provide input, use a tool like `screen` or `tmux` that supports this kind of screen sharing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to see input of data passed to execute by process 6549?

Yes, it is.

```
strace -eread -p6549
```

The *data passed to execute by process 6549* is contained in the output of the above command.